# Impedir rolagem da tela ao abrir modal

Tags: javascript, jquery

Estou criando um site de página única com cinco sessões, cada uma delas pegando por script o tamanho da tela. Em uma dessas sessões, possui um botão que abrirá um modal que ficará a frente de todo conteúdo de todas as sessões.
Com o modal aberto, ainda é possível ver o fundo, e o ideal seria que o fundo não rolasse, apenas o conteúdo do modal, e ao fechar o modal OU chegar ao fim da rolagem do mesmo, a rolagem da página voltasse a ser ativada.

Ou seja, preciso que ao clicar no botão do modal, a rolagem seja desativada e ao fechar o modal ou chegar ao fim dele, a rolagem seja ativada.

Coloquei um evento no botão que faz o conteúdo não se mexer, como desejado, porém ao fechar o modal não consegui cancelar a função.

HTML:

```
  <div id="fullpage">
     <div id="section1" class="section">
        <h1>Sessão 1</h1>
     </div>

     <div id="section2" class="section">
        <h1>Sessão 2</h1>
        <p>Sessão onde o evento acontece</p>
        <button>Botão</button>
     </div>

     <div id="section3" class="section">
        <h1>Sessão 3</h1>
     </div>
  </div>
  <div id="modal">
     <div class="fundo"></div>
     <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="fundo_close"></div>
        <div class="item">Item 1</div>
        <div class="item">Item 2</div>
        <div class="item">Item 3</div>
    </div>
```

CSS:

```
body,html{padding:0;margin:0;}
/* Section styles */
.section{text-align: center;}
.section h1,.section p {color: #333333;margin: 0;}
/* Janela Modal */
#modal{display:none;position:fixed;width:100%;height:100%;top:0;left:0;z-index:101;}
.fundo{background:rgba(0,0,0,.8);width:100%;height:100%;top:0;left:0;position:absolute}
.fundo_close{width:100%;height:100%;top:0;left:0;position:absolute}
.modal-content{width:100%;height:100%;top:0;left:0;position:absolute;}
.item{float:left;position:relative;width:100%;height:50px;margin:15px;background:#fff;z-index:1;}
```

JQuery:

```
$(function() {
    // Initialize fullPage
    $('#fullpage').fullpage({
        //Scrolling
        css3: true,
        scrollingSpeed: 1400,
        autoScrolling: false,
        fitToSection: false,
        scrollBar: false,
        easing: 'easeInOutCubic',
        easingcss3: 'ease',
        loopBottom: false,
        loopTop: false,
        loopHorizontal: true,
        continuousVertical: false,
        normalScrollElements: '#element1, .element2',
        scrollOverflow: true,
        touchSensitivity: 15,
        normalScrollElementTouchThreshold: 5,

        //Navigation
        navigation: true,
        navigationTooltips: ['First section', 'Second section', 'Third section'],
        sectionsColor: ['#f1c40f', '#e67e22', '#c0392b'],
        onLeave: function(index, nextIndex, direction) {
            // Remove the inactive class from all arrows
            $('#fp-nav > span').removeClass('inactive');

            // Add inactive class if needed
            if (nextIndex == 1) {
                $('#fp-nav > span.prev').addClass('inactive');
            } else if (nextIndex == $('.fp-section').length) {
                $('#fp-nav > span.next').addClass('inactive');
            }
        }
    });

    // Add previous and next arrows to the fullPage navigation
    $('#fp-nav').prepend('<span class="prev inactive">&#8593;</span>')
            .append('<span class="next">&#8595;</span>');

    // Re-center the fullPage navigation
    $('#fp-nav').css({ 'margin-top': '-' + ($('#fp-nav').height() / 2) + 'px' });

    // Add actions to the arrows
    $('#fp-nav').find('span.prev, span.next').on('click', function() {
        if ($(this).hasClass('prev')) {
            $.fn.fullpage.moveSectionUp();
        } else {
            $.fn.fullpage.moveSectionDown();
        }
    });
});
// Abre Janela Modal
$("button").click(function(){
    $("#modal").show();
    //Pausa a Rolagem do conteúdo atrás da modal
    $("body").stop().on({
        'mousewheel': function(e) {
            e.preventDefault();
            e.stopPropagation();
        }
     })
});
//Fecha Janela Modal
$(".fundo,.fundo_close").click(function(){
    $("#modal").hide();
});
```

Observem o [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/4o3qLr8j/5/) com o código.

Comment: Esse `fullpage` é *plugin*? A princípio a solução seria incluir uma classe com `body{overflow:hidden}` quando a janela modal fosse aberta e removê-la quando a modal fosse fechada, mas... A documentação desse *plugin* não diz nada a respeito?

Comment: @renan Sim, é um plugin. Ele permite aquelas rolagens onde um scroll você já rola pra tela seguinte, porém depois de eu ter desenvolvido o layout em cima disso, o cliente pediu alteração, ai pra não começar do zero, mantive o plugin.
Li a documentação e não diz nada a respeito.
A ideia seria a sessão funcionar como o site na qual o designer se baseou, porém tal site é um tumblr, o que complica.
[link](http://cinderellapastmidnight.tumblr.com)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Uma solução passa por colocar o `overflow` da página a escondido quando a *modal* é aberta, e reverter quando é fechada.

### Ao abrir

```js
$("button").click(function(){

    $("#modal").show();
    $("html,body").css({"overflow":"hidden"});
});
```

### Ao fechar

```js
$(".fundo,.fundo_close").click(function(){
    $("#modal").hide();
    $("html,body").css({"overflow":"auto"});
});
```

### Ao chegar ao fim da rolagem

```
$('#modal .modal-content').bind('scroll', function() {

    var $conteudo = $(this);

    if ($conteudo.scrollTop() + $conteudo.innerHeight() >= this.scrollHeight) {
        $("#modal").hide();
        $("html, body").css({"overflow":"auto"});
    }
});
```

Nota: Para ser possível detetar o fim do *scroll* dentro da modal, é preciso declarar no css da mesma o `overflow` que funciona em conjunto com a definição de uma altura, algo que já tens no teu exemplo:

```css
.modal-content{
    overflow:auto;
}
```

Ver exemplo neste *clone* do teu [**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/5q24La7m/).

Comment: Realmente funciona. Só que preciso também executar o fechamento do modal ao chegar ao fim da rolagem dentro do modal. Sabe como fazer isso?

Comment: Sei sim, mas dado ser outro assunto, poderias colocar uma pergunta a questionar sobre como detetar o fim do scroll dentro do elemento X ?

Comment: Se colocares a pergunta avisa, de qualquer forma segue a solução: http://jsfiddle.net/zuul/dkhj76fz/

Comment: Na verdade, se olhar o primeiro e segundo parágrafo da pergunta, verá que já noticiei essa necessidade, mas vou analisar o caso do link que mandou.

Comment: Já voltei a ler a pergunta, vou atualizar a resposta... O problema é que é suposto cada pergunta tratar um assunto, a malta aqui no SOpt tende a tratar inúmeros assuntos por pergunta o que torna toda a gestão das respostas um pesadelo :)

Comment: Pronto, a resposta e o exemplo estão atualizados para lidar com ambos os problemas :) Se tiveres alguma dúvida sobre a implementação, está à vontade, deixa um comentário!

Comment: Só consegui voltar a mexer com esse assunto hoje, desculpe, mas funcionou perfeitamente.
E vou seguir sua dica de abordar apenas um assunto na próxima vez. Muito obrigado.