# Abrir Modal sem alteração posição da página

Tags: php, bootstrap

Caros;

Uso o Modal Bootstrap dentro de um While para mostrar imagens capturadas dentro de meu Banco de Dados

Quando tenho diversas linhas, com varias imagens, ao abrir as ultimas por exemplo, o Popup abre sem problemas, porem a página volta ao topo. Existe alguma forma de deixar a página na mesma posição que o popup modal?

**Script que abre o Modal**

```
<script>

$(".abrirModal").click(function() {
   var url = $(this).find("img").attr("src");
  $("#myModal img").attr("src", url);
  $("#myModal").modal("show");
});

</script>
```

**While em PHP para mostrar o modal ao ser clicado:**

```
<td><a href="#"  class="abrirModal"><img width=40px" height="40px" src ="imagem/<?php echo $fetch['imagem']; ?>" /></td>
```

Tentei usar a solução desta pergunta, porem minha página volta ao topo e quando cancelo o modal, perco a barra de rolagem :

[Impedir rolagem da tela ao abrir modal](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/56294/impedir-rolagem-da-tela-ao-abrir-modal)

Comment: Estou meio sem tempo agora, mas acho que seu problema é o `<a href="#" ...`,  tenta substituir por `<a href="javascript:void(null);" ...`

Comment: Boaaaaa, cara me ajudou bastante. Por curiosidade, qual a diferença de um para outro? abs.

Comment: [`<a href="#minhaAncora"`](https://www.w3schools.com/html/html_links.asp) procura uma ancora no html algo como `<a name="minhaAncora"` ou um `<div id="minhaAncora"`, no caso como foi deixado apenas o `#` ele volta para o topo da pagina, já o `javascript:void(null);` esta executando uma função javascript no caso o `void(null)` que não faz nada, poderia ser `javascript:alert(1);`.

Comment: Boa. Muito obrigado. abs

Comment: Parece que teve uma resposta no comentário. Não deixe aberto assim, crie uma resposta. Pode ajudar alguém que tenha a mesma dúvida no futuro.

Comment: @ShutUpMagda já foi resolvido este caso. Consigo assinalar como resolvido?

Comment: Vc pode responder à sua própria pergunta: https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Este tópico foi resolvido com auxilio ao colega @Icaro Martins, da seguinte maneira:

> `<a href="#minhaAncora"` procura uma ancora no html algo como `<a name="minhaAncora"` ou um `<div id="minhaAncora"`, no caso como foi deixado apenas o `#` ele volta para o topo da pagina, já o `javascript:void(null);` esta executando uma função javascript no caso o `void(null)` que não faz nada, poderia ser `javascript:alert(1);`